# Asp Core LLamada de ajax a Controller de MVC siempre retorna Null

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Intente Diferentes formas de llamadas, mismos nombres, con stringify, sin stringify.... pero nada resulta.

mi html

```
    <input type="text" id="txtName"/>
    <input type="button" id="btnGet" value="Get Current Time"/>
    <input type="text" id="txtresponse"/>
```

mi jscript

```
$(function () {
            $("#btnGet").click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
                    data: '{name: "' + $("#txtName").val() + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        //alert(response);
                        $("#txtresponse").val(response);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        //alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

y mi controller es

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult AjaxMethod(string name)
{
    string currentDateTime = string.Format("Hello {0}.\nCurrent DateTime: {1}", 
                                                      name, DateTime.Now.ToString());
    return Content(currentDateTime);
}
```

Aqui, El controller "AjaxMethod" siempre recibe null como valor del parametro "name"

Mi Version es .Net 2022 y .Net 6

Muchas Gracias por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Estas creando el parámetro **data** como un string, y no como un json. Intenta sin las comillas:

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnGet").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Home/AjaxMethod",
            data: {name: "' + $("#txtName").val() + '" },
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            ...
```